# Email and Call logs Button

Tags: email

How to use standard send email and call Logs button on custom object ?

Can anyone answer this ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a Salesforce System Administrator?  Open a custom object record to view its detail page.  If the page is missing a "Send Email" button then ask the System Administrator to add it.  If the page is missing "Activity History" and "Open Activities" then have the System Administrator enable Activities on the custom object as well as add the Activity related lists to the relevant page layouts.

Comment: My pleasure Darshan.  Please accept the answer